# How to keep polls in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache

I would like create simply polls manager (PHP and Apache).

I want for example options:

1. yes or no (boolean in database)
2. select with own option (?)
3. answerbox (varchar 5000)

Moderator have option create new pool. He want for example:

- two yes or no
- one select
- two answer box.

How can i keep this in database? I dont have any idea :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how it can be implemented:

Two types of questions -- `select` (including yes/no questions) and `text`:

```
question_types
--------------
id   type
--------------
1    select
2    text
```

Table `selects` stores all options for the select question type:

```
selects
---------------------------------------------
id   select_id option_desc
---------------------------------------------
1    1         yes
2    1         no
2001 500       optionX
2002 500       optionY
```

Table `polls` stores polls data -- row for each answer with reference to `selects` table for select question. Filled according to your example:

```
polls
-----
id poll_id type  select_id
-----------------------------
10 100     2     1
11 100     2     1
12 100     2     500
13 100     3
14 100     3
```

Table `answers` stores user's answers. answer column references to `selects.id` for select questions and to `answers_texts.id` for texts questions:

```
answers
-----------------------------
id user poll_row_id answer
-----------------------------
1  5000 10          1
2  5000 11          2
3  5000 12          2002
4  5000 13          301
5  5000 14          302
```

The `answer_texts` tables stores answers to the text questions:

```
 answers_texts
 -----------------
 id  answer
 -----------------
 301 text1
 302 text2
```